# JavaFX cannot use onAction on MenuItem

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to make a method to `Exit` the application when `Quit` `MenuItem` is pressed.

I have the following method:

```
@FXML
public void doExit(ActionEvent event) {
    Platform.exit();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

And I receive this error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='doExit', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
project/build/resources/main/Player.fxml:21
```

Line 21 of `Player.fxml` is this:

```
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="doExit" text="Quit" />
```

I have tried to remove/add `@FXML` Notation, the method is not defined as `static` so it should work and I have the right import of `ActionEvent`

Comment: Did you have fx:controller attribute in your fxml file?

Comment: No, but I don't understand why is needed now ? I tried to set it to crassname: Player but it didn't work, coudn't find it.

Comment: It is needed to resolve the "#doExit", otherwise it will not even guess where to look for it ;). Give the full package path to Player, like fx:controller="path.to.my.Player"

Comment: I managed to solve it, I have created the controller programmatically.

Comment: That's great! You can elaborate your findings and "rules of thumb" in your answer below, in a blog entry style.

Comment: The question should remain as a question. Split your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Edit1: Ok, I managed to switch in `Scene Builder` from `Script Mode` to `Method Mode`, this solved the problem but now I am getting:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
project/build/resources/main/Player.fxml:21

        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doExit" text="Quit" />
```

Edit2: I managed to create the controller programmatically because I didn't have any package declaration and I didn't want to create one.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Player.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setController(new Player());
Parent root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();
```

Comment: You could also specify the controller in the fxml file,if you add a attribute to the root  element (see [Uluk Biy's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933003/javafx-cannot-use-onaction-on-menuitem#comment55627161_33933003)). In that case the `FXMLLoader` would create the controller for you (if the default constructor is public).[Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#CACBGIIG). Since you don't keep a reference to the controller,that would be fine too... Just don't use both possibilities at once-otherwise you'd get another error.

Answer (score 0):

The **onAction** accepts a method that accepts ActionEvent as an parameter make sure you are providing a method that  have ActionEvent as argument

Example

**FXML**

```
<Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
   <items>
       <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" fx:id="action_backup" text="Backup" onAction="#performAction"/>
       <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" fx:id="action_settings" text="Settings" onAction="#performAction"/>
   </items>
</Menu>
```

**Java**

```
public void performAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    //you can add this method for multiple menu item and identify
    //each menu item by its id
   MenuItem target  = (MenuItem) actionEvent.getSource();
   System.out.println("Clicked On Item:"+target.getId()); 
}
```

[image: As use by me in one of my project]